# QRegExp to parse function name

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I have these 2 situations:

```
int test(asdf1234, 245234)
virutal void TEST::test(asdf1234, 123)
```

I would like to get the function name "test" out of both of them.

I know I can achieve this using the following:

```
QRegExp regex("...some regex...");
regex.indexIn(str);
foreach (QString part, regex.capturedTexts()) {
    qDebug() << part;
}
```

but I am having issues figuring out how to structure the regex expression.

Any ideas?

Comment: Learn regular expressions.

Comment: Please describe your needs - does it need to work with template class return types? pointers? references? const and other qualifiers? arbitrary number of parameters?

Comment: Btw, are these situations declarations or actual calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(::|\s+)(.+)\(
```

should probably work.  The above translates to: Two colons or some white space followed by one or more characters and then followed by an open parenthesis.

Note, when writing either of the above statements in c++, you have to escape the backslashes in the RegularExpression.  So the first statement would look like:

```
QRegExp regex("::(.+)\\(");
```

I would check out http://regexr.com/ if you want to experiment and learn RegEx better.

The capture groups that come out will show everything that was captured and then the things that were included in parens in the expression.  In this case, the `(.+)` is the only set of parens, so it will be capture group 1.

If you wanted to get really fancy, to try to only get valid [c++ standard names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/565w213d.aspx) of functions and not accidentally pick up `9asdf%$#` as a function name, you could use:

```
([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_\d]+)

(::|\s+)([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_\d]*)\s*\(
```

Or if you wanted to be extremely specific to those two types of function calls you could do something like:

```
((virutal void [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_\d]*::)|(int\s+))([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_\d]+)\s*\(
```

Which translates to: Find the phrase `virtual void _____::` or `int` and some word after it, followed by some optional whitespace and then an open parethesis.

The capture group you would be looking for would probably be: 4, because counting the open parenthesis.

Also for QRegExp, if you want * or + to be greedy operators, you have to use `setMinimal(false);`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#setMinimal

Also be sure to check out:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html

`QRegularExpression` is similar but has some advantages over `QRegExp`.  `QRegExp` is a little older, and may have more examples of it.

Hope that helps.